# How to enable curl, installed Ubuntu LAMP stack?

Tags: ubuntu, php, lamp, curl

I have installed ubuntu Lamp stack.But the curl is not enabled neither i can find extension listed in the INI file, i added manually but it didn't worked too.

How should enable Curl then ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

install the package

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

at this point php should already be configured to load that library [ /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini ]; restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```